# Using ext-js with java /spring

Tags: java, spring, extjs

Hi 
I want to create a simple web app with  java/spring and ext-js and mysql.
Also i want to use hibernate jpa for DAO
but whereever i see , ext-js is used with lamp (php).
Is this possible to use with java.
I just configured my eclipse for ect-js but auto-completion  doent work.I am totally new to ext-js.
Any examples on internet to start whole setup(spring/hib would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/extjs-spring-mvc-3-and?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20javalobby/frontpage%20%28Javalobby%20/%20Java%20Zone%29) you can find a tutorial to integrate exactly the same technology stack you need and here you can find the full source: http://github.com/loiane/extjs-crud-grid-spring-hibernate.

You also probably going to want to watch [this](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/donald-overview-spring-3.0-web-stack) video, introducing spring mvc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Rest Services with JSON stores very well.. All you need to do at backend is responding AJAX requests at controller layer of Spring.